# I need a tutorial for IIS/ASP.Net administration

Tags: iis, asp.net

My technical support staff is only a little familiar with IIS and that's only as far as install goes. They need to install/update and configure ASP.Net web applications and WCF services that we write. Does anyone know any good tutorials/books/web sites that can help them understand some of the basic concepts of web applications and maintaining them on IIS?

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://learn.iis.net/ is the offical web site for IIS 7 and it has all the information you will need to install / configure / maintain IIS hosted web sites.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731055.aspx) on administration is comprehensive and might not be the quick basic concepts tutorial you're after but it's where I went to learn the basics.